# Spring Security Filter showing not found despite being defined in Java config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have configured my Spring application using Java based config. When I start my application, I get the error `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`. I have defined all the configuration classes but this error still occurs. How do I fix this?

My main class:

```
public class SiteMain implements WebApplicationInitializer {    
    private void initSpringMvcServlet(ServletContext container) {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(MvcConfig.class);    
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

    private void initSpringRootContext(ServletContext container) {
      XmlWebApplicationContext rootContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/site.xml");
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
      initSpringRootContext(container);
      initSpringMvcServlet(container);    
    }    
}
```

My Security Initializer class is:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer { }
```

My MVC Config class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
}
```

My Security Config class is:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and().formLogin().loginPage("/").permitAll()
      .and().logout().permitAll()
      .and().rememberMe();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly in your SecurityWebApplicationInitializer class?

Comment: And what is site.xml, what is defined in it?

Comment: @NikolaB: My `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` contains nothing. What I have given is all that is.
`site.xml` contains some beans and a database transaction manager.

Comment: Why don't you create Configuration class and name it BeanConfig or similar and define beans and transaction manager in java config like: @Bean public MyBean myBean() { return new MyBean(); } so you can remove  site.xml and it should work.

Comment: Or you could remove initSpringRootContext() method and add annotation to MvcConfig: @ImportResource({"classpath:/WEB-INF/site.xml"}) . With my previous modifications it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
dispatcherContext.register(MvcConfig.class);
```

with:

```
dispatcherContext.setConfigLocation("your.config.package");
```

add line below:

```
container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));
```

There is no need to @Import(SecurityConfig) since `setConfigLocation` will automatically detect all @Configuration annotated classes.

Comment: According to the docs, the SecurityWebApplicationInitializer class takes care of that. Besides, I am only Java based config and no web.xml

Comment: The `container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(dispatcherContext));` is clashing with the `container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));` and I am getting the error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!`  

  If I remove the `container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));` then the beans which I defined in `site.xml` are not getting initialized.